# image in OpenTBS not changing

Tags: php, opentbs, tinybutstrong

I'm trying to show a series of pictures and comments in a document with OpenTBS. The pictures are hosted on a local webserver. The data is in an array.
In the resulting document the text lines are rendered as expected, but the sample image is not changed.

When I copy paste the url location in my browser it shows a picture without problem.

With setting "$NoErr = false;" there is no error message.

What am I doing wrong?

My template:

```
[imgs; block=begin]
<a sample image>[imgs.url;ope=changepic]
Location: [imgs.url]
Description: [imgs.txt]
[imgs; block=end]
```

In my PHP code (a.o.):

```
$imgs = array();
$imgs[] = array('url'=>'http://192.168.0...', 'txt'=>'Sample 1');
$imgs[] = array('url'=>'http://192.168.0...', 'txt'=>'Sample 2');

$OOo->MergeBlock('imgs', $imgs);
$OOo->Show(OPENTBS_DOWNLOAD, 'file.docx');
```

Update: same problem when I change the url to some public available images on the web.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OpenTBS uses the following 3 functions in order to instert a picture into the current document :

- file_exists()
- filesize()
- file_get_contents()

While the function *file_get_contents()* usually works for an URL, the tow other functions *file_exists()* and *filesize()* return false despite the [PHP documentation says](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.file-exists.php) they can supports http protocol.

So the behavior you have probably come from *file_exists()* returning *false* for you url.

The workaround I suggest is to download the file as a temporary file, then insert it into the document.

Comment: Thank you, your suggestion solved my issue!